# Problema com alocação dinamica - Falha de segmentação

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Defini duas estruturas para representar uma reta. Preciso abrir um arquivo que contem os valores de uma reta por linha, colocar os valores em uma lista encadeada. Isso eu consegui fazer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct{
int x,y;
}ponto;
typedef struct a{
   ponto p1,p2;
   struct a *prox;
}no;
no *aloca_no(){
no *a;
if(!(a=(no*)malloc(sizeof(no))))
    exit(1);
a->prox = NULL;
return a;
}
void incluir_no(no **lista, no*novo){
if(*lista == NULL){
    *lista = novo;
}
else{
    no *aux = *lista;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    while(aux->prox)
        aux = aux->prox;
    aux->prox = novo;
}
}
   void lerDados(no **dadosEntrada, char *local){
FILE *arquivo;
no *acc;
if(!(arquivo = fopen(local,"r")))   
    exit(1);
else{
    printf("Foi\n");
    while(!(feof(arquivo))){ 
        acc = aloca_no();
        fscanf(arquivo,"%d %d %d %d\n", &(acc->p1.x), &(acc->p1.y), &(acc->p2.x), &(acc->p2.y));
        incluir_no(dadosEntrada, acc);
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
 }
}
```

A função `lerDados` funciona perfeitamente, ela chama `incluir_no` para inserir no final da lista. Para cada linha do arquivo lida, a função `lerDados` cria um **nó** e o inclui na lista.
Após ler o dados, se eu executar uma outra função para printar os dados lidos o codigo funciona.

```
void imprime_lista(no *imprime, char *nome){
no *aux = imprime;
while(aux){
    printf("-----------------------%s-----------------------\n%d %d || %d %d\n", nome,aux->p1.x, aux->p1.y, aux->p2.x, aux->p2.y);
    aux = aux->prox;
}
}
```

Porem, se eu tento utilizar uma outra função, que não faz NADA só recebe 2 ponteiros como parametro, occore o erro de falha na segmentação....

```
void retas_verticais(no *dadosEntrada, no *verticais){
printf("uéé");
}
void main(){
no *dadosEntrada, *verticais, *horizontais, *inclinadas;
char local[50]="/home/lua/Workspace/Algoritmos2/dados.txt"; 
lerDados(&dadosEntrada, local);
imprime_lista(dadosEntrada, "Dados Brutos");
retas_verticais(dadosEntrada, verticais);
}
```

Os dados podem ser obtidos daqui -> http://www.edison.unifei.edu.br/publico/COM112/2016-1/COM112_DADOS.txt

Comment: Sua função incluir no esta esquecendo de colocar NULL no prox da lista vazia. (*lista)->prox = NULL;

Comment: Eu esqueci de colocar a função aloca_no, ela deixa o novo nó com o campo prox NULL..

Comment: O nível d eotimização (O2, O3, etc) não deveria alterar o comportamento do seu programa. Se passou  afuncionar com O3 pode ser que tenha sido só sorte... Recomendo que você aprenda a usar um debugador como o gdb ou o ddd. É muito difícil descobrir a causa de uma falha se segmentação só com printf.

Comment: Bugs em compiladores existem, mas geralmente em cantos obscuros da linguagem. Seu problema certamente está no seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente, o problema está acontecendo devido a falta de inicialização da variável `dadosEntrada`.

Como esta variável é declarada na pilha (dentro da função `main`), ela pode conter algum valor diferente de `NULL`, e no teste para inicializar a lista no função `incluir_no`, essa lista não é inicializada corretamente.

Alterei o programa para inicializar a variável logo após a declaração (no `main`):

```
...
no *dadosEntrada, *verticais, *horizontais, *inclinadas;
dadosEntrada = NULL; // <=== AQUI
char local[50]="dados.txt";
...
```

E o programa funcionou sem erros (independente da flag de otimização) com a seguinte saída:

```
Foi
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
10 10 || 25 20
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
29 10 || 29 45
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
90 50 || 90 80
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
20 10 || 90 40
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
90 23 || 0 23
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
15 98 || 15 15
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
90 30 || 50 70
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
90 12 || 90 56
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
10 20 || 90 20
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
50 10 || 80 50
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
20 30 || 40 30
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
54 90 || 54 67
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
40 10 || 40 80
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
50 90 || 10 90
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
0 10 || 57 0
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
60 10 || 50 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
20 10 || 80 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
89 34 || 0 34
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
90 10 || 60 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
67 23 || 67 89
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
70 10 || 20 50
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
78 90 || 78 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
0 34 || 0 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
60 20 || 30 50
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
40 40 || 50 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
12 45 || 78 45
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
20 20 || 30 10
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
20 30 || 20 80
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
46 10 || 67 90
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
0 0 || 89 0
-----------------------Dados Brutos-----------------------
0 0 || 0 0
uee
```

Sem a inicialização dessa variável, ocorre o erro de falha de segmentação.

<sub>testado com gcc version 5.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)</sub>

Comment: Eu consegui descobrir isso ontem de madrugada com a dica do cara de se usar um debugador.. Muito obrigado por me ajudar também!!!! Eu tinha viajado na maionese, eu tinha feito uma função pra inicializar, só q tava errado e não inicilizava, logo eu tinha descartado esse problema hehehehehe